# My image is uploading, but to nowhere it seems (it's not showing at all) - haven't a clue where I'm going wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip

Currently using PaperClip to upload an image file.  In my form I am easily able to update/edit or create a new listing. When I upload an image it only shows up as a broken link and when I click 'open image in new tab' I get a message saying:

No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/missing.png

Am utterly stuck and have no idea whatsoever of what to do next.  Would be truly grateful if someone could please suggest some pointers or tips on what to do?

EDIT:

This is my controller:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listing = Listing.all
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = Listing.create( listing_params )
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1.json
def update
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id]) #find item you want to update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update_attributes(listing_params[:id]) # the refer to it and update it
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end 



  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image)
    end
end
```

Here is my model - I just wanted to upload the file first, irrespective of size.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "200x200", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Here is my development log:

```
Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-09 00:23:48 +0100


Started GET "/assets/listings.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-09 00:23:48 +0100


Started GET "/assets/pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-09 00:23:48 +0100


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-09 00:23:48 +0100


Started GET "/images/original/missing.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-09 00:23:48 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/original/missing.png"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-     4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout   (116.0ms)
```

Comment: post your controller and model.

Comment: Did rails save an image path on your Database when you upload the images. Could you post a log for development to see what parameters is being process.

Comment: @tirdadc I have now posted my controller and model to my original post.

Comment: @PapoucheGuinslyzinho I am not sure if rails saved an image path - I don't think I specified one...how can I check please?  I have now posted a development log to my original post.

Answer (score 2):

HI @USERsomenumbers...

In the Documetation for [Parperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). They showed an example of how should look your Model (listing.rb)

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--iEV2_cUo--/c_fill,fl_progressive,g_north,h_77,q_80,w_137/akjmndys0n7jgpfmf41d.jpg"
end
```

The `:default_url` option stands for a replacement in case that a user didn't upload an image and if you didn't write it in your Model it will have a default url (`'/images/thumb/missing.png'` ... or something similar) but you'll have an error cause there is no routes (link) in your app that has that file. So you should always write a default url OR add a Validation (:presence true) to force the user to upload an image

Also...to verify if your app did save your upload you should log in the console (`rails c -s`)
and `Listing.last`

```
2.1.0 :001 > Listing.last
  Listing Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" ORDER BY "listings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Listing id: 3, name: "34", description: "54", price: #<BigDecimal:93f0120,'0.77E2',9(27)>, created_at: "2014-06-09 06:02:20", updated_at: "2014-06-09 06:02:20", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil>
```

As you see for all the symbol that starts with `:image` the value is `nil` so it means the user didn't upload an image and that rails will look for an image that is set in a `:default_url`

Also you should have this line on your _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @listing,  :url => listings_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to verify if  uploads save.  I have since added a default_url and still receive the same Listing.last message as posted above...does it mean my application doesn't fully 'recognise' what Paperclip is doing?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure if rails saved an image path

Rails / Paperclip will not save an image path - Paperclip will have a folder / file structure where it will save the files you need (this is defaulted to `public/system`)

Paperclip works by taking your file, converting it to an object & saving the following pieces of information to your database:

> - attachment_file_name
> - attachment_content_type
> - attachment_file_size
> - attachment_updated_at

This means your problem is not likely to be with a lack of `image path` from Paperclip. Paperclip is literally just a way to append an image object to your record, allowing you to do something like this:

```
@post = Post.find 1
@post.image.url
```

---

**Validation**

I think your problem is with your [**validation**](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#models)

Paperclip 4 introduced a new type of validation, which checks file spoofing before uploading (basically checks the file type). The way to fix this is to use the following validation:

```
#app/models/listing.rb
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Your other code looks good - I would suggest the problem is your file is not being validated correctly, leading it to not get saved. Either that, or you're calling the file incorrectly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've added the validates_attachment_content_type but it hasn't appeared to make a difference.  Which file do you suspect I am calling incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!! I suspect you're calling the image incorrectly in your view. Are you calling `@object.image.url` ?

Comment: I'm calling it as `<%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>`

Comment: Okay thank you!! Can you confirm you have the image present in your db? If yes, it means Paperclip is saving, if not, it means we've got an issue with Paperclip still!

Comment: According to `Listing.last` All the image fields are coming back as nil, so I don't think it's saving, even though it's saying the 'Your listing has been successfully updated'

Comment: Have you got Imagemagick installed okay? Are there any references to an error in the logs?

Comment: I think ImageMagick installed correctly.  When I go into command prompt and type convert it brings out a long list of commands starting with --

Comment: Nice okay! What about your log? `/log/development.log` ?

Comment: Just had a look, nothing pertaining to ImageMagick comes up, neither do any errors about image uploading.  I'm not sure if this is to do with me working on Windows or if it's a system issue

Comment: I had this exact problem on Windows. What v of ImageMagick are you using?

Comment: Finally got it to work with ImageMagick 6.8.7 Q16(32bit)

Comment: Oh you did?  The version I've been using is 6.8.9-3 Q16 (32Bit).  I've tried looking for the version you got to work, but to no avail...do you know where I may be able to download an older binary version?

Comment: Thank you! I've downloaded and installed it, but it's still not updating properly...do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I can send you my binary files if you like?

Comment: Hi! @userSomenumber :) I  don't really see why it's not working. Last suggestion try to clone a repository on your local machine and see if it's work? you could try this one : (https://github.com/guinslym/paperclip_tuts)

Comment: @userSomenumber ... uncomment the line on my model Listing.rb so that it will correspond to Rick Perk's answer